# How to access AWS S3 bucket and object without credentials

Tags: java, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, ssh-tunnel, aws-sdk-java

I have an application written in aws-sdk-java that read the content from S3 bucket. I am using IAM role to connect S3 from EC2, and using user profile credentials from local environment to S3. Both cases works fine. But I do not want to use user credentials (keys id and sceret accesss keys) from local (eclipse ide). I am searching different options including SSH tunnel to S3 through EC2 instance. As I have seen many example of ssh tunnel to RDS instance but don't find one to S3. Is there any better ways to access S3 bucket without using credentials from local and forward the the to EC2 instance to access S3 from local machine? Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the reason you don't want to use credentials when accessing S3 locally?

Comment: @Andrey The reasons is not to maintain the credentials for every developer. Do you any other idea instead of what I want to do?

Comment: You do have to sign all of your aws api calls with your credentials one way or the other. So unless you can use an EC2 for dev environment (and then use policies to show access to s3), I don't see another alternative but to have your creds on the box.

Comment: @Andrew I understand the use for use of EC2 for dev environment. But  can you please explain "sign all of your aws api calls with your credentials one way or the other" .
However, what about Amazon Workspace where I cane get desktop environment and setup IAM role to access s3.